# CakePHP edit two model at a time

Tags: cakephp

I am new in cakephp.Here I have tow table Broker info and Broker Bank.I have able to send data from BrokerInfosController add method.But problem in edit.

I have used this code for edit

```
public function edit($id = null) {
        $this->BrokerInfo->id = $id;
        if (!$this->BrokerInfo->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid broker info'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
            if ($this->BrokerInfo->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The broker info has been saved'), 'flash_success');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The broker info could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'flash_fail');
            }
        } else {
            $this->request->data = $this->BrokerInfo->read(null, $id);
        }
    }
```

Here BrokerInfo have belongs to relation with BrokerBank.After apply this code I have get this output

[image]

Here how can I send request also for BrokerBank?

I have try like this code

```
$this->request->data = $this->BrokerInfo->BrokerBank->find('all', $options);
```

But It have not worked.

Comment: HI! copy your model associations! i think BrokerInfo hasOne or hasMany BrokerBank ? if you make associatons right, saveAll function will work. and find all Too. This is cake magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this problem by this way,Here is code

```
   public function edit($id = null) {
    $this->BrokerInfo->id = $id;
    $this->BrokerBank->id = $id;
    if (!$this->BrokerInfo->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid broker info'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        if ($this->BrokerInfo->save($this->request->data)) {
            $brokerBank=$this->BrokerBank->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('broker_info_id'=>$id) ,'recursive' => -1));
            $this->request->data['BrokerBank']['id'] = $brokerBank['BrokerBank']['id'];
            $this->BrokerBank->save($this->request->data);
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The broker info has been saved'), 'flash_success');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The broker info could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'flash_fail');
        }
    } else {
        $brokerBank=$this->BrokerBank->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('broker_info_id'=>$id) ,'recursive' => -1));
        $brokerInfo=$this->BrokerInfo->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('id'=>$id) ,'recursive' => -1));
        $this->request->data['BrokerInfo'] = $brokerInfo['BrokerInfo'];
        $this->request->data['BrokerBank'] = $brokerBank['BrokerBank'];
    }

    $tradingTypes = $this->BrokerInfo->TradingType->find('list');
    $accountStatuses = $this->BrokerInfo->AccountStatus->find('list');
    $teams = $this->BrokerInfo->Team->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('tradingTypes', 'accountStatuses', 'teams'));
}
```

Here I think this code is clear what I have done.1st the issue is I need both model `id`. Here I have BrokerInfo model `id` , so I need BrokerBank `id` that I have get by find methods

`$brokerBank=$this->BrokerBank->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('broker_info_id'=>$id) ,'recursive' => -1));`

Than I have define this `id` by this line `$this->request->data['BrokerBank']['id'] = $brokerBank['BrokerBank']['id'];`

So now I can write this line `$this->BrokerBank->id = $id;`

Now the issue how I will read both data in field

Here I have used this four lines

```
$brokerBank=$this->BrokerBank->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('broker_info_id'=>$id) ,'recursive' => -1));
            $brokerInfo=$this->BrokerInfo->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('id'=>$id) ,'recursive' => -1));
            $this->request->data['BrokerInfo'] = $brokerInfo['BrokerInfo'];
            $this->request->data['BrokerBank'] = $brokerBank['BrokerBank'];
```

Here 1st two line find BrokerBank data according to `broker_info_id`  and BrokerInfo by `id`. Than define $this->request->data by field.

I think you have get it.It may poor english but I have tried my best to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Never try, but I think you can have a look to this function:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array

Hope that it can help